# proving $\frac{(a_n-n)}{2}\geq (n-1)\log_2(a_n)$ knowing that $a_n>2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms

I was working on a problem and everything came down to this:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive integers such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N} , a_n\geq 2^n$. prove that there is $m \in\mathbb{N} $ such that for all $n\geq m$, the equality below holds.
> $$\frac{(a_n-n)}{2}\geq (n-1)\log_2(a_n)$$

I wanted to show that the growth of the LHS is much more significant as $n$ gets larger, in fact the LHS kind of doubles every time, but I don't know about RHS. I want more solid reasons, please help me. By the way, please avoid using differentiation, since I am trying to give this solution to 10 and 11 grade high school students, so the more elementary, the better:)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\log_2 x =\frac{\ln x}{\ln2} \leq c\sqrt{x} $ for sufficiently large $x$ and some $c>0.$
Hence $$\frac{a_n -n}{2(n-1)\log_2 (a_n ) }\geq \frac{a_n-\frac{1}{2} a_n}{2n\log_2 (a_n) }=\frac{a_n}{4n\log_2 a_n}\geq \frac{a_n}{4cn\sqrt{ a_n}} =\frac{\sqrt{a_n }}{4cn}\geq \frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{4cn}$$
for sufficiently large $n.$
Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty } \frac{a_n -n}{2(n-1)\log_2 (a_n ) } =\infty$ and hence $$\frac{a_n -n}{2(n-1)\log_2 (a_n ) }\geq 1$$
for sufficiently large $n.$